# Update departure date if arrival date is greater

Tags: javascript, date, calendar

I want to update the departure-date in the calendar when the arrival-date is greater, using JavaScript, adding one day. This is my code but the problem is that when I change the arrival-date, departure-date remains the same.

```js
function addDate() {
   date = new Date();
   var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
   var day = date.getDate();
   var year = date.getFullYear();

   if (document.getElementById('startDate').value == '') {
    document.getElementById('startDate').value = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
   }
   if (document.getElementById('endDate').value == '') {
    document.getElementById('endDate').value = month + '/' + (day + 1) + '/' + year;
   }
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="startDate" style="background-color:#5c677b;height:25px;" name="checkin" placeholder="checkin">

<input type="text" id="endDate" style="background-color:#5c677b;height:25px;" name="checkout" placeholder="checkout">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got that right, you want to:

- Set by default the current date as arrival date and the next day as
  departure date
- Update the departure date when changing the arrival date only if that's greater

My solution is this. Firstly you have to catch the event, by putting a  `onchange="changedDate()"`. Then check if `arrivalDate>departureDate` and when true get that date and finally update the departure date with the next one.

```js
addDate();
function addDate() {
  date = new Date();
  var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  var day = date.getDate();
  var year = date.getFullYear();

  if (document.getElementById('startDate').value == '') {
    document.getElementById('startDate').value = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
  }
  if (document.getElementById('endDate').value == '') {
    document.getElementById('endDate').value = month + '/' + (day + 1) + '/' + year;
  }
}
function changedDate(){
  var arrivalDate = new Date(document.getElementById('startDate').value) ;
  var departureDate = new Date(document.getElementById('endDate').value) ;
  if(arrivalDate>departureDate){
    var arrDate = new Date();
    arrDate.setDate(arrivalDate.getDate()+1);
    arrDate.setMonth(arrivalDate.getMonth()+1);
    arrDate.setFullYear(arrivalDate.getFullYear());
    document.getElementById('endDate').value = arrDate.getMonth() + '/' + arrDate.getDate() + '/' + arrDate.getFullYear();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="startDate" style="background-color:#5c677b;height:25px;" name="checkin" placeholder="checkin" onchange="changedDate()">
<input type="text" id="endDate" style="background-color:#5c677b;height:25px;" name="checkout" placeholder="checkout">
```

Comment: @You're welcome. You may also consider to upvote my answer since it was useful to you.

Comment: i want else change the date format to dd/mm/yyyy when i change it it gives me another date wrong date ? .

Comment: That's not a valid format, read here http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp. You'll have to get it as string, break it to pieces and combine them to your format, or maybe use a library. I'd suggest asking a new question

Answer (score 0):

`If(document.getElementById('endDate').value < document.getElementById('startDate').value){ (document.getElementById('endDate').value= If(document.getElementById('startDate').value.addDay(1) }`

Syntax isn't quite right but that's what you want.

Issue is, you're not telling it to update when you have already selected an end date. If an end date is selected then the start date is changed, you need to compare the two then adjust accordingly.

Comment: yes i am not telling to update the end date.i don't know how , what i want to update end date when start date change , end date will be grater than start date with one day. you got my  point ?

Comment: When and where are you calling the addDate function?

Comment: Then call it again when startDate changes. `document.getElementById('startDate').onChange(addDate ())` and then add the compare if statement.